# How to switch to a different scene without using .hidden to hide UI elements

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I have just recently began learning Swift and Xcode and I have just started programming my first app. At the moment I am using .hidden to hide and show UI elements when the user taps on different functions to switch between different scenes. This seems very messy and unnecessary so I've been trying to figure out a better way to do it. I was experimenting with different things and discovered segues but I am not sure how I would switch to a new scene within a tab without losing the tab bar at the bottom?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would answer my own question now that I have been programming in Swift for a few months now and the answer is obvious...

Rather than hiding and unhiding individual objects, just drag a UIView into the view controller and you can add objects to that. You then simply need to hide the view, to which all of the objects are attached.